# How to connect to remote mysql through two ssh tunnels?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mac-osx, ssh-tunnel

I can ssh into a mysql server via an intermediate host from home:

```
  Peter@home  ->  Ubuntu a.b.com  ->  MySQL on Ubuntu: x.y.org
```

by:

```
  ssh -t peter@a.b.com ssh mary@x.y.org
```

as `x.y.org` only allow ssh from a fixed `a.b.com` ip address, and mysql port 3306 only accessible from `x.y.org`'s 127.0.0.1/localhost.

How can I connect to `x.y.org:3306` through these two ssh tunnels?

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -J <jumphost> -L <localport>::3306 <destination>`